# Can't comment on other posts, able to comment on own

Tags: support, reputation, comments

I can comment on my own answers and questions, but not others.

> [image: Screenshot - can comment]

Is there some reputation rule that I'm not aware of, or is this a bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always comment on your own questions and answers, but you need [at least 50 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to comment on other peoples' posts:

> Amass enough reputation points and Stack Overflow will allow you to go beyond simply asking and answering questions:
>
> ...
> **50**     Leave comments†
> ...
>
> <sup>† you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked, even with 1 rep.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I guess I never really ran into this issue on SO, since my rep was above 50 before I ever really used comments.

Answer (score 0):

As kyle noted, you need 50 rep to do so...  Check out the FAQ for StackOverflow to see the other reputation restrictions, etc.

[stackoverflow.com/faq](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq)