# why can't I comment the answers and questions posted by other people?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

i'm new to http://stackoverflow.com, I want to comment the answers posted by other people in StackOverFlow. but actually, there is no space for me to comment. Is my reputation not enough high? could anyone tell me why?

Comment: "i'm new" <-- that's the reason. You need 50 rep before having comment privileges, although you can always comment on one of your Q or A. See for ex. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32352/cant-comment-on-other-posts-able-to-comment-on-own?rq=1

Comment: Thanks:), that really helped.